# Unity, get AI to run to a transform waypoint, but also away from the player?

Tags: unity-game-engine, artificial-intelligence

This is my first post on here so apologies if I do anything wrong, I read the guidelines so I hope not! So let me get straight into it in a bit more detail.

I'm currently writing AI for a game. What I need to get the AI to do, is to run to a transform waypoint that I have placed on the map (such as an escape), while also not choosing a waypoint that will make them run past the player that has scared them.

I have no clue where to start on this really. I can make the AI run away from the player, but not to a specific waypoint, and I can make the AI get to a specific waypoint, but not both at the same time. Basically all my path-finding is there, I just need a way to choose the appropriate waypoint.

Any help or a point in the right direction at least would be so helpful. Thank you.

Comment: Can you post your code?

Comment: I haven't exactly started on writing anything for this problem yet, as I don't know where to start. I can tell you how my AI is set up though. Basically, I feed in a target transform, and it will head there. That's all there is to it. My issue lies in the logic behind selecting a transform point, for the AI to go to, that is away from the player, so it looks like they're running away, but to a sensible place, like an exit or phone for help (marked out with transforms I need to select for the target).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may want to find path planning algorithms in Google, see which ones fits well with your requisites.

Thinking about it, the Potential Field Path Planning Algorithm comes to my mind. It allows you to set a goal and at the same time avoid obstacles (in this case, the player would be an obstacle).

You can read about it here: http://www.cs.mcgill.ca/~hsafad/robotics/, and search the internet for more information.

[image: Image of the algorithm]

So basically, you have a map, and every point in the map has a vector, the vector should lead you to the goal. Vectors near obstacles move away from it.

Now this is great when you have a static obstacle, because you only calculate the force field, the vector at each point, once, you don't need to keep doing it. But for your case, I guess the player can move, and if the player moves, then you have to calculate again the vectors, so in your case you have to calculate the vector in every point of the map, each time the user moves, so this is not an ideal solution, but it may get you started.

This algorithm also has the problem of local minimums:

[image: S = starting point; T = target]

But I think that's solved in the web page I passed before (they have an example implementation).

If this doesn't do, you may want to search for "Path planning algorithms" in Google, maybe even "path planning with moving obstacles" and treat the player as an obstacle.

**EDIT**

You can try to implement it easily like this:

In these images you can see the AI in Green, the Player in Red, and the Goal in Yellow. The numbers in each square is the distance to goal.

[image: First step]

In this first image you see that the distance starts with 1 in the goal, and increment by one each square, just like that.

[image: Second step]

This second image is just the same, but the value of the squares grows around the player are higher, how much higher you decide, but I made it like that, +2 if its adjacent to the player, +1 if it's a little further.

Now the robot only has to choose the square with lower number. The chosen path is highlighted in gray.

[image: Result]

This last image is the result of summing the values.

In this next example you can see that the AI actually moves a little to the left because it's too near to the player.

[image: Example]

Comment: I was hoping I wasn't going to have to go this deep into things, as I'm using the "A* pathfinding project" as a path-finding solution. I was hoping for a more higher level solution where I could just select a good, predefined point (a transform) that is away from the player. But thank you so much for that detailed post. It's definitely an option if no one can provide a higher-level solution to this. :)

Comment: @WilliamPark I edited the post, look at the images, maybe that's easier to implement and to think about.

Comment: Absolutely stunning help. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

So what was posted above was a little to much for what I'm trying to achieve. I'd have had to root out my whole pathfinding system as it was.

An easier solution to my problem was, instead of checking for the closest transform to the AI, I checked for the furthest one away from my player. This while not perfect, got results that I was happy with, and would usually make the AI run away from the player.